# Unexpected - Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, lambda

Any ideas what the problem might be here on an EF DbContext query? As far as I have understood, this should work according to a [fellow SO poster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18618082/iqueryable-for-entities-where-property-is-in-local-array).

I've tried Lists, null, not null checks, to no avail. The query does work however, if I remove the null check and just leave the `Contains()`. However, it is a requirement to return all records if testIDs is null.

```
var testIDs = new int[] { 1, 3 };
var test = session.All<VendorBooking>(x => testIDs == null || testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID)).ToList();
```

(session.All simply utilises `context.Set<T>.Where()`)

> Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in
>   EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll
>
> Additional information: Cannot compare elements of type
>   'System.Int32[]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity
>   types are supported.

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: what version of EF and .net do you use?

Comment: EntityFramework v6.1.3 (latest AFAIK), .NET 4.5.1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this maybe. Also, you can extract common parts and make it shorter.

```
var testIDs = new int[] { 1, 3 };
if (testIDs == null)
{
    var test = session.All<VendorBooking>()
        .ToList();
}
else
{
    var test = session.All<VendorBooking>(x => testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID))
       .ToList();
}
```

Comment: I see. Or just append to the Where() clause through if/else. Good idea. Thanks. I'm pretty surprised at EF, I would think null checking of arrays should be fundamentally supported.

Comment: @GONeale somethimes EF is very strange, yes

Comment: @GONeale i think, i have an idea, why its happening. In c# (.net) we have collections (arrays, lists and so on), but we have no collections in sql-server. So, linq2sql can not pass collection to server to check it for null

Comment: I would think in the preparation of the query in EF it would simply recognise the array 'testIDs == null' and know to write it as `1 = 1 OR IN (1,2)` etc.. in the T-SQL. That could be done if the EF team took the feature on I think.

Comment: Don't have to do that , You can just do this as I posted in my answer : !testIDs .Any() ...

Answer (score 0):

`testIds` **cannot** be null, so try this

```
var testIDs = new int[] { 1, 3 };
var test = session
   .All<VendorBooking>(x => testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID))
   .ToList();
```

**Revised**

```
var results = (testIds == null || testIds.Length == 0)
  ? session.All<VendorBooking>()
  : session.All<VendorBooking>(x => testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID));
var test = results.ToList();
```

Comment: How can I return all records on cases of testIDs being null if I exclude this check?

Comment: It looks like @Backs has your answer.

Comment: Thanks though Richard.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var test = session.All<VendorBooking>(x => testIDs.Contains()==0 || 
    testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID)).ToList();
```

This is normally working. Don't get confused by the OR operator so only one condition must be `true` for the full expression to be `true`. `testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID)` evaluates to `true` when any value was passed to `testIDs`, otherwise `testIDs.Contains()==0` is true when null was passed.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this :

```
var testIDs = new int[] { 1, 3 };
var test = session.All<VendorBooking>(x => !testIDs.Any() || 
testIDs.Contains(x.VendorServiceID)).ToList();
```

Comment: This causes `testIds` to become part of the SQL query, which isn't necessary at all.